# KM versus Cox model

Tags: survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

This question is in general, but I would also like to know how the answer pertains to building the model in `R`.

I have some time to event data and want to do some survival analysis for it. For sake of example imagine that the response is some time to death value and that I have three groups A, B, and C.  Now if I plot a KM curve for this data, given the fact that I have 3 groups, I will get three curves (one for each group).

No I am fitting the following model in `R`

```
model = coxph(Surv(time,censor) ~ group, data=death.data)
```

where group is a categorical variable with 3 levels pertaining to the three different groups: A, B, or C.

I am using the following command to plot the survival curves

```
plot(survfit(model,xlab ="Time",ylab="Survival"))
```

however, this only plots one curve.  Is this what I should expect?  Really I wanted three curves but am only getting one.

Does this imply that I need to build three survival models?  One for each group, for example one model for group A versus other, one model for group B versus others, etc.?  And if so, could I plot them all on the same graph and this would be equivalent to the KM curve representation?

Answer (score 3):

What `survfit()` does if you do not specify a `newdata` argument is to try to give you a survival curve of an "average" individual. This is usually a bad idea because it is not obvious what you get out of it.

In your case you should specify this way:
`plot(survfit(model, newdata = data.frame("group" = c("group1", "group2")))` and in that case you will get two survival curves, one for an individual with group = "group1" and one for an individual with group = "group2".

For example I generated some data:

```
times <- rexp(30)
status <- rep(1, 30)
groups <- rep(c(1,2,3), 10)

dat <- data.frame(groups, times, status)
dat[dat$groups==1, "times"] <-  dat[dat$groups==1, "times"]+6
```

Then I fit the Cox model and i try to get the survival plots:

```
mod1<- coxph(Surv(times, status) ~ groups, dat)

plot(survfit(mod1)) # an "average" individual, in this case the same as someone from group 2
plot(survfit(mod1, newdata = data.frame("groups" = 1)))
plot(survfit(mod1, newdata = data.frame("groups" = 2)))
plot(survfit(mod1, newdata = data.frame("groups" = 3)))

# Plot all three survival curves in one plot
plot(survfit(mod1, newdata = data.frame("groups" = c(1,2,3))))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What if you also had other covariates in your model, but you just wanted to get an overall predicted survival curve for the groups? In the help file for survfit.coxph() it says: "a data frame with the same variable names as those that appear in the coxph formula."

Comment: For the sake of argument let's say I had the above model plus a factor covariate with 4 levels and an additional continuous covariate. How would I specify a newdata data.frame in order get an 'average' individual on those other covariates, but still create 3 different survival curves for group? I hope this makes sense. I can't find the answer anywhere and i'm not sure if this warrants a separate post.